# Python generate combinations of N in class K

Tags: python, list

I have this code

```
def array_combos(n,k):

    arCombos = []
    i = 0
    a = [0]*k

    while i > -1:
        for j in range(i+1, k):
            a[j] = a[j-1]+1
        i=j
        print(a)
        arCombos.append(a)
        while a[i] == i + n - k:
            i -= 1
        a[i] += 1

    return arCombos
```

The print(a) print right values but list that function return is popolate by one single array n times.
If I use yield insted of popolate list function work perfectly.
Can we help?
Tks

Comment: Add shallow copies, printing works since you are printing snapshots: `arCombos.append(a[:])`. Otherwise you keep adding references to the *same* list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arCombos.append(a)` always append the same, and only, instance of `a`, so you save it to the main `arCombos` multiple times, but there is still one instance that keep being modified.

Pass a copy of it with code like, more at [Get a copy of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-to-prevent-it#answers)

```
arCombos.append(a[:])
arCombos.append(list(a))
```